# how should I use gsap.timeline() in vue3

Tags: javascript, proxy, vuejs3, gasp

I wanna make a motion graph by using **gsap** in **vue3**. I met a question. here is an example below. object-type variable like tl return by ***data()*** is transform to **Proxy** by default. And it dose **not** work when I config it later. So I try to define a variable in ***setup()*** without using ***reactive()***. And it **works** when I config it later.

Run this example, I find some differences exists between tl1(define in setup without reactive()) and tl2.target(define in data()). [You can run it on CodePen](https://codepen.io/letsgo0/pen/wvgYGwV).

Could someone tell me the reason why it dosen't work when it becomes proxy object?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="app" style="width: 5rem;height: 5rem;">
        <button @click="moveOrigin">actionOrigin</button>
        <button @click="moveProxy">actionProxy</button>
    </div>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.6.1/gsap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        const app = {
            setup() {
                const tl1 = gsap.timeline({ paused: true });
                const flag = true;
                return { tl1,flag };
            },
            data(){
                const tl2 = gsap.timeline({ paused: true });
                return {tl2};
            },
            methods: {
                moveOrigin() {
                    console.log("tl1 Origin");
                    console.log(this.tl1);
                    if (this.flag) {
                        this.tl1.to("button", { y: "+=2rem", duration: 1 });
                    } else {
                        this.tl1.to("button", { y: "-=2rem", duration: 1 });
                    }
                    this.flag = !this.flag;
                    this.tl1.play();
                },
                moveProxy() {
                    console.log("tl2 Proxy");
                    console.log(this.tl2);
                    if (this.flag) {
                        this.tl2.to("button", { y: "+=2rem", duration: 1 });
                    } else {
                        this.tl2.to("button", { y: "-=2rem", duration: 1 });
                    }
                    this.flag = !this.flag;
                    this.tl2.play();
                },
            }
        };
        Vue.createApp(app).mount('#app');
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you ever find answer? I'm running into the same issue adapting a projecting from Vue 2 --> 3